# What’s the difference between the notation $(sin(x))^\prime$ and $sin^\prime (x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, trigonometry, notation

What’s the difference between the notation $(\sin(x))^\prime$ and $\sin^\prime (x)$? Where prime denote the derivative of some function. This question seems trivial at first. If we change the argument of function to something different expression of x. The outcome becomes completely different. To give an example, consider the function $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$. We have $(\sin(\frac{1}{x}))^\prime=\sin^\prime(\frac{1}{x})  (\frac{1}{x})^\prime = - \frac{1}{x^2} \cos(\frac{1}{x})$. In this example, we treat $\sin$ function as composite function. We are usually custom to write $(f(x))^\prime$ as $f^\prime (x)$. Perhaps we can not apply this “notation” to this given function. Although, I don’t known the precise  definition of $\sin$ function, I am assuming (due to lack of my knowledge) that, it is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, and it’s range is $[-1,1]$. Since, $(\sin(x))^\prime$ and $\sin^\prime (x)$ are equal for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Isn’t $\frac{1}{x} \in \mathbb{R}$ is also a real number? So, why do we have different outcome for derivative operation? Is $\sin$ function is really a composite function?

**Warning:** My question generally contains error and/or misunderstanding of concept. If you find something wrong then mention it on comment.

Comment: As a general rule, one should strive to avoid  ambiguous notation...though I would have said that both of these mean$\frac d{dx}\sin (x)=\cos(x)$.  Note, too, that $\frac d{dx}\frac 1x=-\frac 1{x^2}$, you lost a sign somewhere.

Comment: I suppose that they mean the same, I would recommend to avoid using $(\sin(x))'$ and stick with $\sin'(x)$ when you mean "the derivative of the function sine evaluated at the point $x$" as some people (myself included) may interpret $(\sin(x))'$ as "the derivative of the constant function whose value equals $\sin(x)$" (of course, such derivative is zero and then I would wonder why you wrote such a convoluted expression for zero!).

Comment: @lulu yeah. I’m sorry for my error. I will fix it.

Comment: @WillM. Thank you for telling the different interpretation of $(sin(x))^\prime$ notation.

Comment: @WillM. If we use $sin^\prime(x)$ notation, then we are stuck in a loop.

Comment: Long story short: I would always stick with $\sin'(x).$ A similar story for $\sin(x)$ over $\sin x.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, $[\sin(x)]'$ is an abuse of notation, since $\sin(x)$ is not itself the function being differentiated, but the output of the function being differentiated: it is an element in the range of the function. So, in any case, if you want to embrace the pedantry, you should use the notation $\sin'(x)$ instead, because now it is clear that you are evaluating the function $\sin'$ at $x$ to obtain the output $\sin'(x)$.

However, there is another reason why you should keep in mind a distinction between $[\sin(x)]'$ and $\sin'(x)$. Suppose we naively replace $x$ with $f(x)$ instead. Now, one would typically interpret $[\sin(f(x))]'$ as an expression where the chain rule is applied: hence you would simplify this as $\cos[f(x)]f'(x)$. But you would never interpret $\sin'(f(x))$ as $\cos[f(x)]f'(x)$. Instead, you would interpret it as $\cos[f(x)]$, since you are taking $\sin'=\cos$, and you are taking $f(x)$ as the input. Because of these shenanigans, you can actually write the equation $$(\sin[f(x)])'=\sin'[f(x)]f'(x),$$ and this would be *technically* correct, even though it definitely does not *look* correct. So the fact is that a distinction is intended to exist, but it works in a way that is extremely misleading. This is the other reason why you should avoid using the notation $[f(x)]'$ and stick to $f'(x)$ instead. And if you really need a notation that allows you to use the chain rule, then instead of writing $(\sin[f(x)])',$ you should write $(\sin\circ{f})'(x)$ to avoid confusion. This makes the distinction between $\sin'[f(x)]$ and $(\sin\circ{f})'(x)$ clear and without any abuse of notation. Hence you can write $$(\sin\circ{f})'(x)=\sin'[f(x)]f'(x),$$ and now the chain rule as applied makes sense visually.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly note that the use of the prime to indicate differentiation is ambiguous in this context. I've never seen it and you should not use it. If you actually encounter it somewhere, hope the context makes the author's meaning clear.

Comment: I think, it is a pretty standard notation used in Baby Rudin book.

Comment: To be more specific, example 5.6.

Comment: @user264745 I'm surprised. I hope it's the unambiguous $\sin^\prime$ that's found there.

Comment: Yeah, I mean you could write $f(x)$ as $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x$ not equal to zero.

Comment: According to your opinion, what notation is best for describing derivatives?

Comment: @user264745 The best notation for derivatives depends on the context. $df/dx$, $dy/dx$, $f^\prime$, $y^\prime$, $Df$ all have their place. I would never write $f(x)^\prime$. If you need the variable name and the prime the prime goes on the function name.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: @user264745 My personal recommendation is to use the $Df$ notation. It is simple to type, and it generalizes more cleanly to higher derivatives: simply write the nth order derivative as $D^n[f]$. It is a notation that is also not visually misleading, and while missing the $'$ can happen due to its size, you will never miss the $D$ symbol. But also, I think your question is the wrong question. What your question is about has a lot less to do with denoting derivatives per se, and more with denoting functions in general.

Comment: @user264745 ...see, consider again the example with $\sin(1/x)$. It is clear that since $\sin'=\cos$, you would write $\cos(1/x)$. But this is not the same as doing $[\sin(1/x)]'=\cos(1/x)(-1/x^2)$, applying the chain rule. It turns out that $[\sin(1/x)]'$ is the wrong notation here, but in order to be able to denote the expression correctly, you need to change the way you denote the reciprocal function. The issue is that the expression $1/x$ is not itself a function, but rather, the output of a function. What you should do is... (see next comment)

Comment: ...is to set $f$ to be a function and define $f(x)=1/x$. Now, instead of writing $[\sin(1/x)]'$ to use the chain rule, you can properly denote it as $(\sin\circ{f})'(x)$. This works regardless of which notation for the derivative you actually use. With this, it is obvious that a distinction exists between $(\sin\circ{f})'(x)$, where the chain rule must be used, and $\sin'[f(x)]=\cos[f(x)]$, where no chain rule is applied.